# Slide not working in api level 21 and above

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on one application and I implement Slide animation but it's not working at all any idea what's wrong with the implementation.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    slide.setDuration(10000);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context = SplashActivity.this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```

Below is the Style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Intent through move another activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
ActivityOptions transition = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashActivity.this);
startActivity(i, transition.toBundle());
```

Another activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.setDuration(10000);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.Just change the theme with Appcompat support theme and its working fine.

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>
```